# View list of VM's set for Autostart - KVM - Fedora Host with LibVirt

Tags: kvm-virtualization, fedora

I'm looking for a non gui way (CLI) to find all VM's that have Autostart configured on my Fedora KVM Host.

Comment: Fly by downvote with no comment?

Comment: If only I could learn what to improve to not get downvotes, but without input I can't...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The obvious thing would be:

```
# virsh list --autostart --all
 Id    Name                           State
----------------------------------------------------
 -     vpn-fr-1                       shut off
```

You could also:

```
# ls /etc/libvirt/qemu/autostart
vpn-fr-1.xml
```

Comment: Here I was going to parse the output of `virsh dominfo` in some script. Didn't realize it was an option for `virsh list`.